# MAMP Pro 3.5.2 hangs when quitting on Mojave 10.14

Tags: mamp-pro

Stopping the server is fine, but when I try to quit MAMP PRO, it hangs (v3.5.2). Anyone knows of a solution? Thanks.

Comment: Haven't upgraded to Mojave yet, but I'm not happy to hear this...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing and running Mamp Pro 5?

Comment: Yes, that would be the logical choice obviously, I just can't upgrade at the moment.